# PHP: Implode an array and use each array value multiple times

Tags: php, implode

What I want to achieve is the following:

transform an array:

```
['A','B','C'];
```

into a string like:

```
"A is A, B is B, C is C"
```

Is there any other way than a foreach-loop (like implode) to achieve this?

Comment: You could use `array_map()` or `array_reduce()`.

Comment: array_map() is possible, but needs a variable assignment, so it can't be used simply, when i want to concatenate it with another string immediately.

Comment: https://eval.in/627981

Comment: @Anant: thanks. this is the way i do it at the moment - the standard solution.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not looking to loop through, you could use [array_walk()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) function.

Try this:

```
$input = ['A','B','C'];

function test_alter(&$item, &$key) {
    $item = $item.' is '.$item;
}
array_walk($input, 'test_alter');
echo implode(', ', $input);
```

Output:

```
A is A, B is B, C is C
```

Comment: I also thought of a solution like that (reference style) - the best solution at the moment. what about printf?...

Comment: print_f is used to print using a format specifier. That has nothing to do with converting an array to string.

Comment: Why are you making the key variable modifiable by reference? Even if you could, you don't use that variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr = ['A','B','C'];

function myfunction($arr)
{
    return "$arr is $arr";
}

print_r(array_map("myfunction",$arr));
//[0] => A is A [1] => B is B [2] => C is C
```

Comment: Nice solution. Usable as a one-line like that: `echo implode(', ', array_map(function($v){ return "$v is $v"; }, $arr));`

Answer (score 0):

use below way with array_walk

```
$arr = ['A','B','C'];
function _print($item2, $key)
{
    echo "$item2 is $item2, ";
}
array_walk($arr, '_print');
```

or if need to save in string use below

```
    $arr = ['A','B','C'];
    $str = '';
    function _print($item2, $key)
    {
        global $str;
        $str = $str."$item2 is $item2, ";
    }
    array_walk($arr, '_print');
    echo trim($str,',');
```

Comment: `global` declaration should only be used when no other method is suitable -- as shown by other answers, `global` is not needed to generate the desired output string. Generally, you would just pass the `$str` value as a function argument (and make it modifiable by reference).

Answer (score 0):

Here's my recommendation, since you're accustomed to using implode in php, I wrote you a duplicate function that takes a formatter element in your separator. Anywhere you put %x will duplicate the array key like so:

```
echo implodeDuplicate(" is %x, ", $myArray);
```

assuming $myArray was:

```
$myArray = array(1,2,3,4);
```

it will output:

```
1 is 1, 2 is 2, 3 is 3, 4 is 4,
```

Here's the function:

```
function implodeDuplicate($seperator, $array) {
    $finalString = "";
    for($i = 0; $i < count($array); $i++) {
        $trueSep = str_replace("%x", $array[$i], $seperator);
        $finalString .= $array[$i] . $trueSep;
    }
    return $finalString;
}
```

Hope it's helpful! :)

Comment: Thanks. But too complex :-)

Comment: What's to complex about it, or what don't you like? I'll see if I can tweak it for you.

Comment: You are doing many things, that are not required to solve the problem. See upvoted solution of yogesh, edited by u_mulder. Its clean, simple and can be directly used as a one-liner.

Answer (score 0):

I see `array_map()` and `array_walk()` solutions, but no one posted an `array_reduce()` method, so I will for completeness.

For small arrays (few iterations required), `array_map()` will execute ever-so-slightly faster (your users will never notice the difference).

As the input array increases in size, `array_reduce()` takes the lead and distances itself from `array_map()`.  Do your own benchmarks with your own real data if you *need* to perform micro-optimization.

- `array_reduce()` on 26-element array looped 100 times: https://3v4l.org/1oCXM/perf#output
- `array_map()` on 26-element array looped 100 times: https://3v4l.org/WcjMB/perf#output

My following method doesn't need `implode()` because `array_reduce()` outputs a string, however it does need a conditional on each iteration to avoid "over-gluing".

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/GWkkn))

```
$input = ['A', 'B', 'C'];
echo array_reduce(
         $input,
         fn($result, $v) => ($result ? "$result, " : '') . "$v is $v"
     );
```

Or here is `array_map()` with arrow function syntax then `implode()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/1SArA))

```
echo implode(
         ', ',
         array_map(
             fn($v) => "$v is $v",
             $input
         )
     );
```

Output:

```
A is A, B is B, C is C
```